# Create GateKeepr exceptions for all files in a folder

Tags: macos, script, gatekeeper

I downloaded a software in `tar.gz` form.
It is built from a `bin` folder and `lib` folder.

It is blocked from running since files are from the Internet.
I wanted to make an exception for the program yet there are many binary files.
On the Internet I found how to add exceptions only to `.app` files.

Is there a way to add exceptions for all files in a folder and sub folders?
Maybe by a script?

Comment: What happens if you delete the quarantine attribute from these "internet" files?

Comment: What's the software? [I'm just surprised at anyone distributing Mac software as .gz]

Comment: @Tetsujin, https://julialang.org/downloads/. If you can download the Apple in `tar.gz` and make the binary work, that will be perfect.

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin - it would have been a whole lot easier to just download the dmg with the fully-built app inside it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjDNs.png

Comment: @Tetsujin, Indeed. But in my case there are reasons to work with the `tar.gz`. Do you have an idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quarantine attribute from all files in a folder:

```
xattr -c -r /path/to/folder
```

Comment: I searched and saw an answer with `-r -d` which didn't work. What's the difference in this?

Comment: OK, I looked at https://ss64.com/osx/xattr.html. `-c` means remove all attributes. I will try this.